# How to prove that there is always a path in a DAG that goes through all vertices in a chain?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science

Consider the following claim.

Let S be a set of vertices in a DAG (directed acyclic graph), G. There is a path in G that goes through all vertices in S IFF S is a chain.

I can see the truth of the claim in the forward direction but not in the backward direction. Namely, I can't prove

If S is a chain, then there is a path in G that goes through all vertices in S.

The definitions I used for paths and chains are the ones found in [Mathematics for Computer Science](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f2/Mathematics_for_Computer_Science_by_Eric_Lehman%2C_F._Thomson_Leighton%2C_and_Albert_R._Meyer.pdf)(path in page 371 [page 379 in the pdf] and chain, Definition 10.5.5., in page 381 [page 389 in the pdf].

Additionally, if the claim is true, is it still true if G is a directed graph instead of a DAG.

Comment: So can you see that the chain is defined as: $C_n=(V,E),$ where $V=\{1,\cdots ,n\}$ and $E=\{(i,i+1):1\leq i\leq n-1\}.$ Graphically it is a line with $n$ points. Can you construct the path using this?

Comment: @Phicar No, I don't think the definition of a chain is the one you are referring to. Please see page 6 in https://openlearninglibrary.mit.edu/assets/courseware/v1/2efbd5ad05fcdbccf1dbdb789cbb19af/asset-v1:OCW+6.042J+2T2019+type@asset+block/MIT6_042JS15_Scheduling.pdf

Comment: "sequence of subjects that
must be taken in order" that is exactly what is encoded in that definition.

Comment: @Phicar Check out the first slide in page 6. The set of subjects `8.02`, `6.004`, and `6.857` is a chain, but edges `(8.02, 6.004) and (6.004, 6.857)` don't exist in the graph. You can also check out the accompanying lecture video of the slides at https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=17&v=1TpzSCMLg08

Comment: What do you mean they do not exist? I see the arrows in the slide you are pointing out. Can you clarify what is wrong with the definition above?

Comment: @Phicar The graph under consideration is the one in the third slide of page 5. The first slide on page 6 is just depicting a set of vertices from that graph that is a chain. The arrows in the first slides on page 6 must be a mistake. If you check out the lecture video above, things will become clear.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, i was oversimplifying in the comments. Sorry
Consider a set $S=\{s_1,s_2,\cdots ,s_k\}$ to be a chain then all of them are comparable(by definition), meaning that they are of the form $s_1\leq \cdots \leq s_k$ where $a\leq b$ means that there is a path from $a$ to $b$ in the DAG. Then, we have a path from $s_1$ to $s_2,$ another path from $s_2$ to $s_3$ and so on. Call the path from $s_i$ to $s_{i+1}$ $p_i,$ and then concatenate the paths as $p_1p_2\cdots p_{k-1},$ this will be a path from $s_1$ to $s_k.$